# How to refresh ListView automatically?

Tags: android, listview, sms, refresh

In my app, i am populating `ListView` with received and sent `SMS`. Here is the code :

```
public class ChatActivity extends ListActivity {

private MyListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> item_id = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_phone_num = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_msg_body = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_time = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> item_flag = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
private Button btn_send;
DbManager manager;
Cursor Cursor;
ViewHolder holder12;
String contact_for_chat;
String contact_no;
String message_body = "";
Calendar c;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
String time;
EditText et_chat;
String flag;
String msg = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    contact_for_chat = bundle.getString("contact_name");
    contact_for_chat = contact_for_chat.replace(" ", "");
    contact_no = Util.getContactNumber(contact_for_chat, ChatActivity.this);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contact_no, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    manager = new DbManager(this);
    Cursor = manager.Return_SMS(contact_for_chat);
    showEvents(Cursor);

    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    time = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    setActionBar();
    findViewsById();
    adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SendSMS();
            refreshCursor();
        }
    });
}

protected void SendSMS() {
    SmsManager sms_manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    message_body = et_chat.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms_manager.divideMessage(message_body);
    sms_manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(contact_no, null, parts, null, null);
    flag = "1";
    manager.Insert_sms_data(time, contact_for_chat, message_body,flag);
    updateUI();
    msg+= "SMS to :" + contact_for_chat + " \n";
    msg += "having number:" + contact_no + " \n";
    msg += "as" +message_body + " \n";
    msg += "at"+ time + " \n";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private void setActionBar() {
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_chat, null);
    TextView tv_chat = (TextView)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    tv_chat.setText(contact_for_chat);
    ColorDrawable colorDaawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CFCFC4"));
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDaawable);
    mActionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}

private void updateUI() {
    et_chat.setText("");
    refreshCursor();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


private void findViewsById() {
    et_chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_chat);
    btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {

    item_id = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_phone_num = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_msg_body = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_time = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    item_flag = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    int i=0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        item_id.add(i+"");
        item_time.add(cursor.getString(1));
        item_msg_body.add(cursor.getString(3));
        item_phone_num.add(cursor.getString(2));
        item_flag.add(cursor.getString(4));
        i++;
    }

  }
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context con;
    private LayoutInflater layoutinf;
    ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ArrayList<String> items_ = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyListAdapter(ChatActivity context) {
        con = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return item_id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item_id.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return item_id.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        View v = arg1;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (v == null) {
            layoutinf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.row_chat, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tv_contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_num);
            holder.tv_sms_body = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        if(item_flag.get(position).equals("1"))
        {
            holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);

        }
                    else if(item_flag.get(position).equals("0"))
                    {
                        holder.tv_sms_body.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

                    }

        holder.tv_contact.setText("" + item_phone_num.get(position));
        holder.tv_sms_body.setText(item_msg_body.get(position));
        holder.tv_time.setText(item_time.get(position));

        return v;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {

    private TextView tv_contact;
    private TextView tv_sms_body;
    private TextView tv_time;

}
private void refreshCursor() {

    manager.open();
    Cursor = manager.Return_SMS(contact_for_chat);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    manager.close();
}
```

I want that as soon as `SMS` is received or sent,`ListView` should be updated automatically. I have tried it using 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
but its not working . How can i make my app `ListView` updated as soon as `SMS` is sent or received. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just use a [Simple]CursorAdapter and everything will update automagically, no need for notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 1):

notifyDataSetChanged tells the listview to reload its data.  Its still going to call the adaptor functions getView and getItemCount to do this.  Those need to return the correct new data.  However, you're not updating the data they return-  you're only setting the item_id array in onCreate.  Since the array is never changed, the list view is never updated.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```